# Python - Getting output of socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am trying to get the output after the lolimessage was sent but i get no output

```
try:
    xmr = ''
    data = s.recv(1024)
    d = data.decode("UTF-8")
    xmr += d
    if "loli" in xmr:
        s.send(lolimessage + enter)
        print("Loli Sent")
    else:
        print("loli NOT sent")
except:
    s.close()
try:
    xmr = ''
    data = s.recv(1024)
    d = data.decode("UTF-8")
    xmr += d
    print(xmr)
except:
    print("fail to print")
    s.close()
```

The loli part works and prints out data but on the 2nd try i get "fail to print", can any1 plz help

Comment: could it be that the socket is closed after the first try/except part?

Comment: That's the danger with a blanket try/except.  It could be hiding errors completely unrelated to the socket.  For example, if `enter` is a regular string and not a byte string, you'd get an error, and you'd never know it.  Get rid of the try/except and make it work first.

Comment: In both try/except blocks, you're deliberately hiding the real error.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: You are suppressing helpful exceptions. You should at least call "print_exc" from module "traceback" in the except-blocks to see the error message.

Comment: The question is missing the necessary information to help. It provides no information about the behavior of the server side, no error messages (since any errors get discarded) and not enough client and server code to be understandable or  reproducible by others.

Comment: To see errors, do smth like `import logging` and then at least `except: logging.exception("ouch")`. Ideally `except Exception: logging.exception("ouch")` to avoid catching low-level exceptions like `SystemExit`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`s.send(lolimessage + enter)`
send it in bytes with encoding

`s.send(bytes(lolimessage + enter, "utf-8"))`